# dict of class types as argument and dict of their instances as return type

Tags: typescript

I want to write a function which accepts as a argument a dictionary whose values are classes, and on the output I would like to get a dictionary with their instances

e.g

```
classes C1, C2
function f: ({
    name1: C1,
    name2: C2
}): ({
    name1: new C1()
    name2: new C2()
})
```

How could i write types to function f to get strong typing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do it with mapped types and the built-in conditional type `InstanceType`

```
class C1 { c1!: number} 
class C2{ c2!: number }
type AllInstance<T extends Record<string, new (...a: any[]) => any>> = {
    [P in keyof T]: InstanceType<T[P]>
}
function f<T extends Record<string, new () => any>>(o: T): AllInstance<T> {
    const result = {} as AllInstance<T>
    for(var key of Object.keys(o) as Array<keyof T>) {
        result[key] = new o[key]()
    }
    return result;
}

let o = f({ C1,C2 })
o.C1.c1;
o.C2.c2;
```

[link](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCCM0De1jwIQC5oDsCuAtgEYCmATgL7QBQokMsATCsI1roaWdBdQC4BPAA4loAQRAgAkjgh8wOYCQA8AFWgkAHnxI4AJjABKJYAHsye5XLIBLHAHMANLhIB3aAAoAdD7DYFAgDaALoAlNAAvAB80AFRMRHI1NAp0IEACtB20ADWJAKmAGbQqsHYMnIKSqrCKqoZwVHUvIV4inw2pjjQhWoa2roG0MZmFlZ8tg7OOG6e4dGxOALxHqbYqqHYEtKy8op1MUjJqWa70GQkEHggfJHIVJDikhV7SmpNqT3mHgBuYNx5ATQIrQADyRAAViY+F5ARBVuFHmIyGQwAJlICQaoouEjp9PhcrjdAoDgncZu5TCT8sEPKFjileASSHw8GRuoTrnwANzNajUEAs4F3QoeFAIRxMHj00xeBBeNC82VMBWMblAA)